# How to merge an array and an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to merge an array and an object together, but I can't find the right way to do it properly.

```
var array = [[1, 5, 6, 9]]; // from 
var object = {toto: 4, titi: "tutu"};
```

If I have these two variables and want to merge them into one, how do I proceed ? Knowing that I want the output to be an array.

I know it can be done within a loop

```
var merge = [];
for(var val of array)
{
  merge = [].concat(val);
}
merge.push(object);
```

but I'm looking for a more succinct way to do it.

I would like to obtain something like this :

```
  var result = [1, 5, 6, 9, {toto:4, titi:"tutu"}]
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, I have not been specific enough on the need I have.

So I showed here a solution with loop that use small and simple arrays and object. But I will need to handle more complex arrays (and multidimensional arrays) and object. My solution will still work but I also have to worry about performances and so I'm looking for a more efficient solution.

My goal is for the solution to be as efficient as possible in order to be able to use this in any situation, regardless of the client performance, for any kind and size of arrays and object.

I currently need this on a code that is already quite heavy (using map with moving object in real time) and so I'm trying to improve performance everywhere I can.

I also want to know if it is possible to do this without having to concat each and every one of the possible arrays I could have in my original array. (I don't want to have repetitive code)

But in the end if concat and loops are the most efficient I'll stick with that.

**EDIT 2**

For example I would like to have the same type of result as my example with this kind of array and object :

```
var depthArray = 
               [
                 [[1, 2, 5, 8], ["toto", "titi", 8]],
                 [["data", "blob", 6], [8, 5, 2], [7, "tata"]],
               ];

var depthObject = 
                {
                  data:
                       {
                         x: 1,
                         y: {z: 5},
                         t: "time",
                       }
                }
```

And as a result it would look like that :

```
var depthResult = [1, 2, 5, 8, "toto", "titi", 8, "data", "blob", 6, 8, 5, 2, 7, "tata", {data:{x:1, y:{z:5}, t: "time"}}]
```

Comment: `var merge = array[0]; merge.push(object);`

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem here? Your code works just fine, and is probably more reliable considering possible values in your input variables.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand where you might be stuck. You seem to know `concat`, so you know how to add things to an array. Do you not know how to access the `[1, 5, 6, 9]` inside the `[[1, 5, 6, 9]]`?

Comment: It works just fine when use on small and simple and small arrays and objects like here, but I need to worry about performances and will need to handle more complex and big object and arrays
I'll edit to be more specific

Comment: @EdgeSouls: So, did you _try_ it with more complex data? Why are you worrying about performance? Did you notice the performance to be an issue?

Comment: your edit does not add some more data structure to the question and a wanted outcome as well. as it is written, it is nearly not possible to give an answer, which fullfill the given need, which is actually not given. to optimize a pice of code, a data structure and some according code have to work and the could bi optimized for faster run, if even necessary. right now, any answer is speculative and does not help you.

Comment: can you giving more details about the kind of structure you're managing ?

Comment: A maximum source array depth ? I can see you are using a for|of loop, make your array fetchable via an iterator, but have you wrote a bench to ensure what you said about perf. (try [jsperf](http://jsperf.com))

Comment: I have edited the post to be more specific about what kind of arrays and objects I want to use

Answer (score 0):

You could take the first array out of the array and concat the object to it.

```js
var array = [[1, 5, 6, 9]], 
    object = { toto: 4, titi: "tutu" },
    result = array[0].concat(object);
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why did someone downvoted it? It answers the question! OP is most probably trying to work something out on somebodies code with no javascrpit knowledge (well, happens) and that is tow answer.